# Angular : How to extend HttpClient?

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-httpclient

I did not find in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http) how to extend HttpClient or how to specify different interceptors for some of my HTTP requests. In documentation, they explain how to set interceptors in `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` but every HTTP requests are intercepted.

I need to have customizes HttpClient implementations to set specifics Headers, endpoints or response interceptors (I don't want to use Restangular, I would prefer to use the built-in angular HttpClient implementation).

- I have an  oAuth API with a specific endpoint and specific header to set my api-key.
- I also have my "resources" API that needs specific header (`Authorization: Bearer` ... and API-KEY) and a specific response interceptor to catch all HTTP 401 responses.
- Maybe, i will need to call some externals API without any interceptors

I know this is possible with Restangular but I prefer to use `HttpClient`. How is it possible ?

I found [this article](http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/) but, this is for `Http` not for the new `HttpClient` implementation of angular.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of extending HttpClient, I would take one of three approaches:

1. Have each of your Interceptors inspect the URL of the request, and either do it's work, or just call `next.handle(req)` without doing anything else, depending on the URL

or

2. Write a delegating Interceptor, that decides which other Interceptors to delegate to, depending on your requirements.

or

3. Just write one big Interceptor that decides what do based on the URL / whatever you need.

My gut would be to go with #1

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think this approach doesn't respect separation of concerns (except for the first one ?!). But if I use the interceptors to set the api endpoints, I will not be able to inspect URL ?!

Comment: I wasn't suggesting setting the endpoints in the Interceptors, just setting whatever headers are required for the particular endpoint. I would think that your services should be responsible for knowing the endpoint url.

Comment: Each of my custom `HttpClient` implementation has its own constant URL endpoint and I don't want to use a `getURLEndpoint()`-like method.

Comment: just like @GreyBeardedGeek said It's not a good practice to set hard-coded URI endpoints into your providers. But if you don't want to change, you could use approach #1 or #2 easily.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting setting (hard-coding) the endpoints in the providers...